# Scraping Google nGram data

Tags: import, internet

What is the most direct and efficient way to scrape the raw data graphed in a Google ngram search, such as [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Artemisia%20Gentileschi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CArtemisia%20Gentileschi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CArtemisia%20Gentileschi%3B%2Cc0)?  (I want to analyze, edit, plot, and label it in *Mathematica*.)  The obvious `Import` methods do not scrape the raw data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In chrome, after you run the ngram query, you can go to the "Developer tools", find the source file starting with `graph?content="`, search for the string `var data` (search is under the triple dots on the upper right corner), and find the time series `var data = ...`

Comment: Oh... so close... (thanks!)... but...   I do a mouseover and see the end of var `var data` but somehow cannot copy it, or find the raw file URL to `Import`.  Again, I'm so close... can you push me across the finish line here?  (Sorry... I'm not a web developer.)

Comment: Ah... GOT IT!  (Scroll to the proper line then copy the full line.) This is *SO* helpful.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$)